# I need to write this same program but with a while loop instead of a for loop

Tags: python

Here's the original code:

```
def scrollList(myList):
    negativeIndices = []
    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        if myList[i] < 0:
            negativeIndices.append(i)
    return negativeIndices
```

and here's what i've got so far:

```
def scrollList2(myList):
    negativeIndices = []
    needMoreNumbers = True
    while (needMoreNumbers):
        if myList[i] < 0:
            negativeIndices.append(i)
        n = n-1
        if (n<1):
            needMoreNumbers = False
            return negativeIndices
```

Right now I'm getting the error "global name 'i' is not defined which I know it's not but I don't know how to go about defining 'i' without a for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting a global error on `i` is that you've not defined it anywhere. You have to define what you use. You've also not defined the variable `n`. After fixing `i` you'll get an error on that too.

So, define `n` in front of the `while` loop like so

```
n = len(myList)
while(needsMoreStuff):
```

and change the reference to `i` to be

```
if myList[n] < 0:
  negativeIndices.append(n)
```

should suffice to fix your error.

**Edit**:

Suggested a different looping construct and then edited it to be more in keeping with the question. Problem is an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just simulate it with a counter variable:

```
def scrollList2(myList):
    negativeIndices = []
    counter = 0
    while (counter < len(myList)):
        if myList[counter] < 0:
            negativeIndices.append(counter)
        counter += 1

    return negativeIndices
```

Comment: @Migol Good catch, I forgot about the indexing. Fixed.

Comment: You also have not defined `i`.

Comment: and well, `counter` is kinda bad practice as standard name for this variable is `i` or `index`

Comment: Come on, the whole code is _bad practice_ according to Python's standards! Using a `while` to create a list? I just wanted to make my point!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try manually doing indexation.

```
def scrollList2(myList):
  negativeIndices = []
  index = 0
  while (index < len(myList)):
    if myList[index] < 0:
      negativeIndices.append(index)
    index+=1
  return negativeIndices
```

Comment: Two space indents is bad practice for Python ;)

Comment: Not to mention you don't have `i` declared, you declared it as index so `myList[i]` and `append(i)` will fail? See? Everyone makes mistakes, I just don't downvote so loosely ;)

Answer (score 0):

the pythonic answer is

```
indices = [i for i,n in enumerate(mylist) if n<0]
```

or use () instead of [] for a generator (to dynamically generate them one by one)

Comment: Yes but the question says _with a while loop_. So I guess we don't get to be so pythonic in this one.

Comment: @PauloBu well, i am solving a programming question, not a homework question.